# Como consumir web service XML SOAP https com C# .Net Core 2.0?

Tags: c#

Fiz a referência ao WSDL pelo WCF do Visual Studio 2007, e criei uma classe simples para testar a comunicação, não consigo entender o que está errado, recebo o erro : "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority".

Já fiz várias pesquisas pela web e aqui pelo stack, mas nada funcionou.

Fiz um teste com o webservices do correio, que também está em Https, funciona tranquilamente, mas ao executar a chamada ao outro dá esse erro. 
Pelo SoapUI, funciona normalmente, alguém pode dar ajuda?

```
try
{

  VV_OptOutClient Soapclient = new VV_OptOutClient();

  var soapreturn = await Soapclient.atualizarOptOutAsync(obj);

  return soapreturn.retornoOptout;

}
catch (Exception e)
{

  throw new Exception(e.Message);

}
```

Comment: Como ficou a configuração do seu endpoint no arquivo de configuração?

Comment: Eu apenas adicionei uma referencia aos serviços conectados, ai a o serviço de referencia foi criado, o que me permite acessa-lo pelo VV_OptOutClient, entendeu?

Comment: Entendi, veja no web.config ou no appsettings como está configurado o endpoint

Comment: Acredito que esteja em ordem, foi criado o padrão.
  "ExtendedData": {
 "Uri":"https://dominio/vv/operacao_lojas/optout/atualizar/SOAP/v1?wsdl",
    "Namespace": "WSOptOut",
    "SelectedAccessLevelForGeneratedClass": "Public",
    "GenerateMessageContract": false,
    "ReuseTypesinReferencedAssemblies": true,
    "ReuseTypesinAllReferencedAssemblies": true,
    "CollectionTypeReference": {
      "Item1": "System.Array",
      "Item2": "System.Runtime.dll"
    },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom,

Não encontrei solução ao Usar Referências(WCF), então fiz com WebRequest mesmo, ignorando protocolos Tls, Ssl, e burlando a validação do certificado.

Se por acaso alguém um dia encontrar uma resposta, por favor inclua.

Muito obrigado!